# Must one perform the sunnah/nawafil prayers as well as the fard?

Tags: salat, sunnah, fard

As we all know almost all prayers consist of Sunnahs, Nawafils and Fard. For example, the the Dhuhar prayer consists of,

- 4 rakat Sunnah,
- 4 rakat Fard,
- 2 rakat Sunnah,
- 2 rakat Nawafils.

Now my question here is, is it OK if I only pray the four Fard as these are an obligation (as the name suggests), or is it equally important to perform the Sunnahs and Nawafils as well? I have seen many people just performing Fard rakats of each prayer so i'm a little confused about that.

Will my prayer get accepted if i only perform the obligatory Fard Rakats? (I.e. 2 Fajr, 4 Dhuhar, 4 Asr, 3 Maghrib, 4 Isha with 3 Vitr)?

Comment: you must pray Fard prayers but for Sunnah think about it as a bonus its not a must ,, i mean if you did it you will be reward but if not its ok,, sunnah is optional but prefer to do it

Comment: Uh- yeah, it looks the same as the mentioned link as you pasted. Ahsant.

Answer (score 0):

**According to Shia Islam, this is just obligatory (Wajib) to prayer our main prayers (those 17 Rek'ats) and as it is clear from its name, they are Wajib, not Mustahab (recommended). Then as a rule, Allah won't torment us because of the Mustahab prayers.**

**Hence Muslims at least must say their main 17 Rek'ats. Of course I don't mean that you leave other prayers, but it means that you ought to prayer those 17 rek'ats as a Mandatory duty.**

besides, rationally, if Allah doesn't term other prayers as Wajib Salah, thus it shows that they are not Wajib, then Allah won't torment us for the prayers which he did not call them as Wajib salahs. Otherwise he would term them Wajib.

**I mean:**

> Fajr : 2
>
> dhuhr : 4
>
> Asr : 4
>
> Maqrib : 3
>
> Isha : 4
>
> Totally : 17 Rek'ahs

As a result, we ought to pay attention that Mustahab deeds (such as Mustahab prayers) are not mandatory, but you'll obtain more Thawab (reward) if you do them, otherwise why does Allah them as Mustahab (recommended) deed?!

[www.tebyan.net](http://www.tebyan.net/newindex.aspx?pid=934&articleID=232508)